# Why do PostgreSQL arrays have different starting indices for 1D and 2D arrays?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working with point data in the form `(p1, p2)`, which is represented in text as `((x, y), (x, y))`. I would like to get 4 values out of this string (`x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2`), But I'm having trouble working with array indices.

For example:

**(1) Get a `point[]` representing the 2 points**

```
select concat('{', replace(replace('(64,38),(-26,-40)', '(', '"('), ')', ')"'), '}')::point[];

-- This correctly gives me {(64.0,38.0),(-26.0,-40.0)}
```

**(2) Get the first point from that array**

```
select ( select concat('{', replace(replace('(64,38),(-26,-40)', '(', '"('), ')', ')"'), '}')::point[] )[1]

-- this gives me (64.0,38.0) (i.e. index = 1 gives me the FIRST point)
```

**(3) Get the x value of the first point**

```
select ( select ( select concat('{', replace(replace('(64,38),(-26,-40)', '(', '"('), ')', ')"'), '}')::point[] )[1] )[0]

-- This gives me 64 (i.e. index = 0 gives me the FIRST point)
```

It seems that in a 2D array, indices start at 1. But in a 1D array, indices start at 0. How can this be????

I've tested this on `Dbeaver` and separately on `PG Admin 4` and I get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a two-dimensional array, you have an one dimensional array of points.  That is not the same thing, even if they do have some similarities.  I think a "point" is a type implemented as a fixed length array type, as discussed in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html)

> For historical reasons (i.e., this is clearly wrong but it's far too late to change it), subscripting of fixed-length array types starts from zero, rather than from one as for variable-length arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the value `{(64.0,38.0),(-26.0,-40.0)}` is not actually a 2D array. it's an array of points.

A point, although it looks like an array is not one. When accessing elements of a point, indexes start at 0.